# Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments - Angular 5 http calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular5, angular4-httpclient

I'm trying to fetch data from API using interface.
Bellow is my temp interface

```
export interface ITemp {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    age:  number
}
```

And below is my HTTP service, where there is a fn getHomedetails, which calls an API.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ITemp } from "../interfaces/temp";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService{

    http:any;
    baseUrl: String;

    constructor(http:HttpClient){
        this.http = http;
        this.baseUrl = 'some_url';
    }

    getHomeDetails(): Observable<ITemp>  {
        return this.http.get<ITemp>(this.baseUrl); //problem is here 
        //when mouse is pointed on get<ITemp> it shows "Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments"

    }

}
```

An interface doesn't get defined. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. And the above syntax is an angular 4.3X syntax.
The editor which I've used are the sublime and visual studio.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is because you're giving your class-level `http` a type of `any`:

Change `http:any;` to `http: HttpClient`

A good rule of thumb is to not use `any` unless you really really have to.

Comment: it's interesting how similar this guideline is to .NET policy of do not use pointers unless you really really have to and if you do the compiler will force you to label your code as "unsafe" and change your project configuration to "allow unsafe code".

Comment: My code actually specifies HttpClient as the type of the variable,  it's actually almost exactly the same as OPs code with that exception, so I'm at a loss, as I'm not using the "any" type for anything in the erroronous .ts file

Comment: Create a minimal reproduction in Stackblitz and the issue should be spottable.

Comment: I appreciate the diligence, but it turns out I was operating in a nested function and so the variable scopes were different.  Fixed it by creating a utility function like nishil's pattern